# phpMyAdmin tries to allocate unreasonable amount of memory

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

`PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 140649765932120 bytes) in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://testhost.test/phpmyadmin/`

This Error Message suddenly apears in my PHP error log and phpMyAdmin does not work after entering a database and performing a search on a table.

The amount is always that huge which looks like the value somehow overflowed. How do I fix this?

**Edit:** The Error is not bound to a specific Database. It happens at random times after 3-x clicks. As I tried to find a pattern that allows me, to narrow the cause I ended up pressing F5 a few times in a row which leads to a white page. So I looked in the Apache Error-Log which shows:

> [Mon Nov 10 08:49:24.839881 2014] [core:notice] [pid 5561] AH00051: child pid 7107 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

I tried to find the mentioned coredump, but was unsuccessful. phpmyadmin version is 4.0.6deb1.

Comment: something's very wrong with your DB if you've got a record that big...

Comment: Are you able to browse that table without trouble? From the Structure tab of the database (not the table), what is the size and row count for this table? Also, what version of phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I added some information above. The error is not bound to a specific table and my (very limited) knowledge sugests, that it might be a php-problem!?